# AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, attributeerror, findall

I am trying to parse an XML with namespace,
The  XML looks like

```xml
<DATA xmlns="http://example.com/nspace/DATA/1.0"  xmlns:UP="http://example.com/nspace/UP/1.1" col_time_us="14245034321452862">
<UP:IN>...</UP:IN>
<UP:ROW>
     <sampleField>...</sampleField>                
</UP:ROW>
<UP:ROW>
     <sampleField>...</sampleField>                
</UP:ROW>
.
. 
.
</DATA>
```

When I use the following code to parse the XML

```
tree=ET.parse(fileToParse);
root=tree.getRoot();
namespaces = {'UP':'http://example.com/nspace/DATA/1.0'}
for data in root.findAll('UP:ROW',namespaces):
        hour+=1
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

When I try to iterate through the children of root and print the tags, I get `{http://example.com/nspace/DATA/1.0}ROW` as the tags instead of just ROWS.

I want to find the ROW elements and extract the value for the sampleField tags. Could anybody please guide me as to what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ElementTree `Element` objects indeed have no `findAll()` method. The correct method to use is [`Element.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall), all lowercase.

You are also using the wrong namespace URI for the `UP` namespace. The root element defines **two** namespaces, and you need to pick the second one:

```xml
<DATA xmlns="http://example.com/nspace/DATA/1.0"  
      xmlns:UP="http://example.com/nspace/UP/1.1" ...>
```

Note the `xmlns:UP`, so use that URI:

```
>>> namespaces = {'UP': 'http://example.com/nspace/UP/1.1'}
>>> root.findall('UP:ROW', namespaces)
[<Element {http://example.com/nspace/UP/1.1}ROW at 0x102eea248>, <Element {http://example.com/nspace/UP/1.1}ROW at 0x102eead88>]
```